# Implementar medias y 95%CI para cada subconjunto de datos usando ggplot

Tags: r

Tengo un conjunto de datos que más o menos son así (nótese que esto es un ejemplo mínimo y que lo limitado de los datos puede afectar a la apariencia visual del gráfico obtenido):

```
y    x   z    g
1    0   0    1
2    1   0    1
2    0   0.5  1
3    1   0.5  1
1.5  0   1    1
2    1   1    1
2    0   0    2
2    1   0    2
3    0   0.5  2
3    1   0.5  2
0.5  0   1    2
2    1   1    2
2    0   0    3
2    1   0    3
1    0   0.5  3
1    1   0.5  3
0.5  0   1    3
0.5  1   1    3
```

Me gustaría representar en un gráfico la media de y para cada posible combinación de x & z. Representando y en el eje vertical y g en el eje horizontal.

Hasta ahora he utilizaro el siguiente código:

```
means <- tapply(y,g,mean)
plot(means, col="red",pch=18, ylim=c(0,3), type = 'l', ylab='y', xlab="g")
```

Después, para cada conjunto de datos (para cada posible combinación de x y z que realizo manualmente con `subset`), dibujo una nueva línea en el gráfico, con un color diferente. Uso este código:

```
lines(means, col="black",pch=18)
```

Me gustaría poder realizar el gráfico de una manera menos engorrosa, utilizando ggplot. También me gstaría implementar los intervalos de confianza del 95%.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola pyring, puse una respuesta. No estoy seguro de que sea lo que estás buscando, porque no me que queda del todo claro en la pregunta. ¿Podría pegar la imagen con la salida que obtenés después del subset, etc.? De todos modos puse una respuesta con el dataset de test que subiste y lo que entendí de la pregunta. Probalo con tus datos reales a ver que pasa.  De paso, una sugerencia: en los data set de pruebas que incluyes en tus preguntas trata de no usar como nombres x, y, z. Confunden un poco la terminología pq por convención así llamamos a los ejes de un gráfico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumo que querés un punto por cada media de *y* condicional a `g`, `x` y `z`. Con tu test data serían nueve puntos, por cada punto una barra de error con el CI al 95% y una línea que una los puntos a los largo de `g` cuando tienen la misma combinación de `x` y `z`. 
En ese caso podrías hacerlos así:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Genero una estructura de datos manejable en R. 
tribble(    ~y,    ~x,   ~z,    ~g,
             1     , 0,   0    ,1,
             2     , 0,   0    ,1,
             2     , 0,   0.5,  1,
             3     , 0,   0.5,  1,
             1.5   , 0,   1    ,1,
             2     , 0,   1    ,1,
             2     , 1,   0    ,2,
             2     , 1,   0    ,2,
             3     , 1,   0.5,  2,
             3     , 1,   0.5,  2,
             0.5   , 1,   1    ,2,
             2     , 1,   1    ,2,
             2     , 1,   0    ,3,
             2     , 1,   0    ,3,
             1     , 1,   0.5,  3,
             1     , 1,   0.5,  3,
             0.5   , 1,   1    ,3,
             0.5   , 1,   1    ,3) -> datos  #Le asigno nombre. 

  datos %>%
  group_by(g, x, z) %>%                                 #Agrupar. Los estadística que se calculan luego son para cada combinación de las variables de agrupamiento. 
  summarise(media = mean(y),                            #Estimación de la media para cada grupo
            desvio = sd(y),                             #Las desviación estándar.                             
            error_est = desvio / sqrt(n()),             #Error estandar. 
            intervalo_sup = media + (2*error_est),      #Techo del intervalo. 
            intervalo_inf = media - (2*error_est)) %>%  #Piso del intervalo al 95%.
  mutate(clave = paste("x",x,"z", z, sep="")) %>%       #Genero una clave única para cada combinación de x y z. 
  ggplot(aes(x = g, y = media, color = clave)) +
  geom_point() +                                        #Para que genere una salida gráfica cuando sólo hay un data point.
  geom_line(aes(group = clave)) +                       #Las líneas que unen los puntos de cada grupos xz
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = intervalo_sup,               #Techo del intervalo con la variable que calculé al principio.  
                    ymin = intervalo_inf),
                width=0.1) + 
  theme_minimal()
```

Que produce este gráfico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es mejorable, las barras de error se superponen y no es muy legible. Dependerá de los datos reales con los que estés trabajando.

Comment: Hola @mpaladino. Los datos, en efecto, al tratarse de un ejemplo mínimo, pueden afectar a la percepción visual del gráfico. He editado la tabla de datos y he añadido un comentario para hacer notar el hecho. Por otra parte, el código que facilitas funciona muy bien. Tan solo añadir que ha sido necesario escribir línea de código `data %>%` al inicio para ejecutar el código correctamente. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola @pyring! Que bueno que te sirva el código. Después edito la respuesta para completarla y documentarla mejor. Supongo que con un data set más grande queda más completo el gráfico. Lo que no me gusta mucho de la opción que te doy es que al superponerse las barras de error en el eje x son un poco difíciles de leer.

Comment: Claro, eso se debe a los datos. Si pruebas a generar un dataframe mayor verás que los 95%CI's se dibujan correctamente. Si tienes problema con ello no tengo inconveniente en proporcionarte unos datos en un dropbox.

Comment: Creo que no hace falta si el código te funciona. La salida gráfica en la respuesta es para ilustrar el resultado y validar el código.